# count how many number 5 appear in range 1 to 1000

Tags: php, arrays

This is an interview question.
In range 1 to 1000, interviewer want me to count how many number 5 appear but in programming language like PHP or java etc (specially in PHP).
 I can't figure out how to solve this question. maybe here i can have the perfect solution.
i have try like this in PHP

```
$numbers = range(1, 1000, 1);
echo array_count_values($numbers)[5];
```

i know that was wrong code because it echo 1
if you know please tell me, thanks

Comment: So the question is how many times 5 appears as a digit in those numbers? Your best bet is treating the numbers as strings and checking whether there's a 5 in there.

Comment: i'm quite sure "the interviewer" isn't really interested in whether SO can solve this problem - SO isn't applying for a job :-)

Comment: Also, the requirement isn't completely clear - is 555 supposed to be counted as one occurrence or three?

Comment: @El_Vanja can you write your solution as code? because I really didn't get the picture

Comment: i think 555 is count as one not three

Comment: Show us a sample of your expected results...

Comment: I am not willing to provide a straight answer for a job interview problem - that would be unethical. I'm not the one applying. If you're unable to solve it, consider that maybe you're not the best candidate for the job. I've pointed you in the right direction, now it would be up to you to research it further; how to turn the number into a string, check if string contains a specific character... all of these topics are basics and have been well covered both on and off the site.

Comment: i think my expected result like this, for example in 1 to 20, number 5 is appears twice (5 and 15), if in 1 to 25 number 5 appears 3 times (5, 15 and 25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

$numbers = range(1, 1000, 1);

$count = 0;

array_walk($numbers, function($value) use (&$count) {
    $count += substr_count($value, '5');
});

?>
```

Response is: 300 numbers five appear in that range.